# Symmetry of circular distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, circular-statistics, symmetry

I wanted to ask somebody for an opinion about one thing I found in the statistical book (Mardia, Jupp - Directional statistic).

They were defining circular symmetric distribution in following sense:

The distribution of circular random variable $\theta$ is symmetrical about the $\mu,$ if the distribution is invariant under the transformation
$$\theta \rightarrow \mu-\theta.
$$
And if the $\theta$ is symmetrical about $\mu$ and has density $f(\theta),$ then 
$$f(\theta-\mu)=f(\mu-\theta).
$$
So my point is, is the transformation right? Based on my knowledge from linear case I would say it should be $\theta \rightarrow 2\mu-\theta.$

And the second question is, I believe that both the transformation and the equality between densities, should be with respect to$\mod 2\pi.$
And of course, I am not sure about the equality up there, if there should not be something like $f(\mu-\theta)=f(\mu+\theta)$?

Comment: The reflection about the angle $\mu$ changes the angle $\theta$ (which is defined only modulo $2\pi$) into $2\mu-\theta$ (which therefore *must* be defined modulo $2\pi$).  As far as your last question goes, what ensues when you plug in (say) $\mu$ for $\theta$?